# How can I extract a particular element of Wikipedia table in R using rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

For example, for NYC I want to extract the website from infobox (the table on the right).

I'm using this:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City"
page = read_html(url)

links = page %>%
  html_nodes("table tr a")
```

But that's wrong.

Comment: Done. I'm sorry.

Comment: consider either posting an answer or deleting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xpath` you could first get the infobox by its class name `infobox` and then all links via their tag name `a`.

```
library("rvest")

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City"
infobox <- url %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//table[contains(@class, "infobox")]//a')

print(infobox)
```

Output

> ```
> {xml_nodeset (81)}
>  [1] <a href="/wiki/City_(New_York)" class="mw-redirect" title="City (New York)">City</a>
>  [2] <a href="/wiki/File:NYC_Montage_2014_4_-_Jleon.jpg" class="image" title="Clockwise, from top: Midtow ...
>  [3] <a href="/wiki/Midtown_Manhattan" title="Midtown Manhattan">Midtown Manhattan</a>
>  [4] <a href="/wiki/Times_Square" title="Times Square">Times Square</a>
>  [5] <a href="/wiki/Unisphere" title="Unisphere">Unisphere</a>
> ...
> ```